# Change refactoring templates of VisualStudio 2017 (MethodContracts)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, refactoring

I like the new refactoring tools of Visual Studio 2017, especially the creation of code contracts you can access by the screwdriver icon:

[image]

Currently I create "argument checks" with custom code snippets. I would love to use refactoring, but the generated code is not how I would like it. Is it possible to change the refactoring templates?

This is what is currently generated by Visual Studio:

[image]

This is what I want to produce with the refactoring:

[image]

My changes should convert the statement to a "one liner". Additionally, the message parameter has a predefined message text.

I looked already in the CodeSnippet directory but could not find the template I have to update.